# Add Panel dynamically to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jpanel

I have empty space below menu bar which i need to fill with dynamic panels on action events. suppose user clicks on File->New a new Panel will be added to the empty space.
I tried creating a panel and adding on action but it didn't worked.

```
JFrame.add(panel);
JFrame.revalidate();
JFrame.repaint();
```

How should i proceed and what is the best way.

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: I can't add a pic because of less reputation. i am using netbeans for creating the app. i want to add panels on jframe on an action event.

Comment: Don't want a pic, want a runnable example which demonstrates you problem, so we see and try your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Cardlayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html)

A card layout shows just one component on top, while the others are hidden (a bit like a deck of cards).

```
JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.add(card1, "New");
cards.add(card2, "Save");
cards.add(card3, "Edit");
```

Use an action listener on your menu items or buttons. When a user selects a menu item, say 'new', then you might have some code that looks like this :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

    CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) cards.getLayout();
    cardLayout.show(cards, "New");

}
```